# In C++, can a C-style cast invoke a conversion function and then cast away constness?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

GCC and Clang both reject the C-style cast in the following code.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6fb8797d9d96a27

```
struct S {
    typedef const int* P;
    operator P() { return nullptr; }
};
int main() {
    int* p1 = const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int*>(S{}));
    int* p2 = (int*)(S{});
}
```

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:25: error: invalid cast from type 'S' to type 'int*'
     int* p2 = (int*)(S{});
main.cpp:7:15: error: cannot cast from type 'S' to pointer type 'int *'
    int* p2 = (int*)(S{});
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, according to the standard, a C-style cast can perform the conversions performed by a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`. Is this code well-formed? If not, why not?

Comment: Does it work with 2 c-style casts ie `(int*)(const int*)(S{})` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, but that's not the question ;)

Comment: C++11 §5.4 about the cast notation does not mention any limitation of not invoking user defined conversions. On the contrary §5.4/3 states that "Any type conversion not mentioned below and not explicitly defined by the user (12.3) is ill-formed.", which explicitly drags in the possibility of invoking a user-defined conversion.

Comment: I've been chasing around the spec for a while now trying to figure this one out. The spec is pretty unclear about how it determines what types it uses when trying to do the `static_cast` and the `const_cast`. If it tries to do them in the way that you've described, it absolutely would work, but if it tries to just do `const_cast<int*>(static_cast<int*>(S{})))`, then it will definitely fail. I have no idea how the compiler would know to try to add `const` here, but the spec doesn't seem to say anything on the subject...

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me: [expr.cast]/4.3 says that this should work, so the compilers are bugged.

Comment: @templatetypedef obviously the "static_cast followed by const_cast" case will use different types for the two cases, since one will be const-qualified and one not

Comment: @M.M Well that's the thing - the spec doesn't actually say that the compiler should attempt to add `const` anywhere. It just says "try a `static_cast` and then a `const_cast`," not noting how to choose which type to use for the `static_cast`.

Comment: @M.M I mean, I agree with you that it *should* do that, but I don't see anywhere in the spec that explains what specific choices it should try, which is weird given how detailed it is everywhere else.

Comment: @templatetypedef that's entirely up to the compiler to figure out. The spec doesn't need to provide any more detail.  It even gives an example where conversion fails due to there not being a unique sequence, which suggests it is intended that the compiler try out all possible sequences (in a similar way to other conversion situations). Maybe a compiler vendor would say it's too hard to implement and the spec should specify a narrower set of possibliities, IDK.

Comment: @template reading it, I think it does not specify what type to use for the static cast.  It says if you can do the conversion with *a static cast* it must be done, however.  The compiler must prove that *no type* in the static cast, followed by *no type* in the const cast, to convert to the target type, before eliminating that option.  In practice, this problem is actually easy (in some cases?  Hmm, 10 pointers?), but the standard just makes the demand and does not specify the details.  Or what mm said.

Comment: @Yakk perhaps Brian's case is invalid because `static_cast<int const *>` followed by const_cast is possible, but so is `static_cast<int const * const>` followed by a const_cast therefore it is ambiguous. But I think this suggests the standard wording is defective as templatetypedef suggests

Comment: `int* p1 = const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int*const>(S{}));` does that cause an issue?  Multiple different legal `static_cast`s?

Comment: @m.m damn you.  30 seconds this time.  But "If a conversion can be
interpreted in more than one way as a static_cast followed by a const_cast, the conversion is ill-formed." -- I think that is a sufficient justification to make this illegal under the (current draft) standard.  And maybe not a sufficient justification for it to actually *be* illegal.  Wonder if a there is a way to check if that is the actual reason it is rejected?  Or if that makes other seemingly acceptable cases with no user defined operator equally illegal, yet supported?

Comment: @Yakk http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/363feac2631bafce

Comment: @brian aha compiler bug!  :)  (well standard bug really)

Comment: The extra const seems meaningless, but regardless one can always cast to `const volatile` and then `const_cast` both away.

Comment: @t.c. meaningless, but the standard says if there is more than one valid `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast` the cast is ambiguous (assuming the c-style cast gets that far).  Unless there is some wording that the top-level `const` or `volatile` on a static cast is "meaninless" or the like...  This is pretty stupid, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [core issue 909](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#909):

> According to 5.4 [expr.cast] paragraph 4, one possible interpretation
>   of an old-style cast is as a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`. One
>   would therefore expect that the expressions marked #1 and #2 in the
>   following example would have the same validity and meaning:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   operator const int* ();
> };
>
> void f(S& s)  {
>   const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int*>(s));  // #1
>   (int*) s;  // #2
> }
> ```
>
> However, a number of implementations issue an error on #2.
>
> Is the intent that `(T*)x` should be interpreted as something like
>
> ```
> const_cast<T*>(static_cast<const volatile T*>(x))
> ```
>
> **Rationale (July, 2009):**
>
> According to the straightforward interpretation of the wording, the example should work. This appears to be just a compiler bug.

This was apparently never resolved by neither Clang nor GCC. Time to open tickets.