# Does the C++ specification say how types are chosen in the static_cast/const_cast chain to be used in a C-style cast?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer

This question concerns something I noticed in the C++ spec when I was trying to answer [this earlier, intriguing question about C-style casts and type conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39215125/501557).

The C++ spec talks about C-style casts in §5.4. It says that the cast notation will try the following casts, in this order, until one is found that is valid:

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `static_cast` followed by `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.

While I have a great intuitive idea of what it means to use a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast` (for example, to convert a `const Derived*` to a `Base*` by going through a `const_cast<Base*>(static_cast<const Base*>(expr))`), I don't see any wording in the spec saying how, specifically, the types used in the `static_cast`/`const_cast` series are to be deduced. In the case of simple pointers it's not that hard, but as seen in the linked question the cast might succeed if an extra `const` is introduced in one place and removed in another.

Are there any rules governing how a compiler is supposed to determine what types to use in the casting chain? If so, where are they? If not, is this a defect in the language, or are there sufficient implicit rules to uniquely determine all the possible casts to try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If not, is this a defect in the language, or are there sufficient implicit rules to uniquely determine all the possible casts to try?

What about constructing all types that can be cast to the target type using only `const_cast`, i.e. all "intermediate types"?

Given target type `T`, if `static_cast` doesn't work, identify all positions where one could add cv-qualifiers such that the resulting type can be cast back to `T` by `const_cast`<sup>1</sup>. Sketch of the algorithm: take the cv-decomposition ([[conv.qual]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1)) of `T`; each *cv*<sub>j</sub> can be augmented. If `T` is a reference, we can augment the referee type's cv-qualification.

Now add `const volatile` to all these places. Call the resulting type `CT`. Try `static_cast`ing the expression to `CT` instead. If that works, our cast chain is `const_cast<T>(static_cast<CT>(`*e*`))`.

If this doesn't work, there very probably is no conversion using `static_cast` followed by `const_cast` (I haven't delved into the deep corners of overload resolution (well I have, but not for this question)). But we could use brute force to repeatedly remove `const`/`volatile`s and check each type if we really wanted. So in theory, there is no ambiguity or underspecification; if there is some cast chain, it can be determined. In practice, the algorithm can be made very simple, because the "most cv-qualified" type we can construct from `T` is (assuredly) sufficient.