# Why does this C-style cast not consider static_cast followed by const_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

Consider:

```
float const& f = 5.9e-44f;
int const i = (int&) f;
```

Per [expr.cast/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4) this should be considered as, in order:

> - a `const_­cast`,
> - a `static_­cast`,
> - a `static_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
> - a `reinterpret_­cast`, or
> - a `reinterpret_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,

Clearly a `static_­cast<int const&>` followed by a `const_­cast<int&>` is [viable](https://godbolt.org/z/xbfPfMbj3) and will result in an `int` with value **0**. But all compilers instead initialize `i` to **42**, indicating that they took the last option of `reinterpret_­cast<int const&>` followed by `const_­cast<int&>`. Why?

Related: [In C++, can a C-style cast invoke a conversion function and then cast away constness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215125/in-c-can-a-c-style-cast-invoke-a-conversion-function-and-then-cast-away-const), [Why is (int&)0 ill-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581849/why-is-int0-ill-formed), [Does the C++ specification say how types are chosen in the static_cast/const_cast chain to be used in a C-style cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216316/does-the-c-specification-say-how-types-are-chosen-in-the-static-cast-const-cas), [Type punning with (float&)int works, (float const&)int converts like (float)int instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454585/type-punning-with-floatint-works-float-constint-converts-like-floatint)

Comment: Converting a `float` to an `int` is not the same thing as converting a reference to a `float` into a reference to an `int`. Whether the reference is const-qualified is immaterial.

Comment: `const` is a red herring and distracts from the real problem. Consider this simplified complete example : https://godbolt.org/z/oaxz31j99

Comment: I think it has something to do with lvalue reference to non-const not being allowed to be bound to prvalues.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `const` is necessary to allow a `static_cast` chain to work; you need to construct a temporary.

Comment: @ecatmur I think I understand. You would expect `(int&)` to `reinterpret_cast` for a `float f;` but expect it to `static_cast` + `const_cast` for a `const float & f` because in the second case `f` is a reference type?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux actually I'd expect it to `static_cast` + `const_cast` in both cases, since there is a viable path (via `int const&` binding to a temporary `int`). But in the latter case it should be blatantly obvious to the compiler that the path exists, since it's the exact same sequence of types with the `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @eerorika it *is* allowed, though; see https://godbolt.org/z/xbfPfMbj3

Comment: @ecatmur No prvalue is bound to a reference to non-const in your example with two casts.

Comment: @eerorika oh, my bad. So if the static_cast followed by const_cast is valid, why aren't the compilers selecting it?

Comment: @user17732522 you linked to this question - did you mean to link to a different one?

Comment: Oops, I meant that this is related, although the answer here is better and probably applies as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581849/why-is-int0-ill-formed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr:

- `const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(f))` is valid c++
- `(int&)f` should have the same result
- but it doesn't due to an ancient compiler bug that never got fixed

  - [open std issue 909](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#909)
  - [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77465) (confirmed, but never fixed)
  - [clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30266)

---

#### Long Explanation

##### 1. why `const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(f))` works

###### 1.1 the `static_cast`

Let's start with the `static_cast<int const&>(f)`:

- Let's check what the result of that cast would be:
  [**7.6.1.9 Static cast**](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#1) (emphasis mine)

  > <sup>(1)</sup> The result of the expression `static_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. If `T` is an **lvalue reference type** or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue; if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue. The static_­cast operator shall not cast away constness ([expr.const.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast)).

  `int const&` is an lvalue reference type, so the result of the `static_cast<>()` must be some sort of lvalue.
- Then let's find out what conversion actually happens:
  [**7.6.1.9 Static cast**](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#4)

  > <sup>(4)</sup> An expression `E` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` if there is an implicit conversion sequence ([over.best.ics](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics)) from `E` to `T`, [...].
  > If `T` is a reference type, the effect is the same as performing the declaration and initialization
  > `T t(E);`
  > for some invented temporary variable `t` ([dcl.init]) and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

  - In our case the declaration would look like this:
    `const int& t(f);`
  - I'm not going to elaborate the entire conversion process here to keep it short, you can read the exact details in [12.2.4.2 Implicit conversion sequences](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics)
  - In our case the conversion sequence would consist of 2 steps:

    - convert the glvalue float to a prvalue (this also allows us to get rid of `const`)
      [**7.3.2 Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion**](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval) (emphasis mine)

      > <sup>(1)</sup> A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If `T` is a **non-class type**, the type of the prvalue is **the cv-unqualified version of `T`**. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is `T`.

      Given that `float` is of non-class type, this allows us to convert `f` from `float const&` to `float&&`.
    - convert from float to int
      [**7.3.11 Floating-integral conversions**](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint)

      > <sup>(1)</sup> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

      So we end up with a nicely converted `int` value from `f`.
- So the final result of the `static_cast<>` part is an lvalue `int const&`.

###### 1.2 the `const_cast`

Now that we know what the `static_cast<>` part returns, we can focus on the `const_cast<int&>()`:

- The result type needs to be:
  [**7.6.1.11 Const cast**](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#1) (emphasis mine)

  > <sup>(1)</sup> The result of the expression `const_­cast<T>(v)` is of type `T`. If `T` is an **lvalue reference to object type**, the **result is an lvalue**; if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue and the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard conversions are performed on the expression `v`. Conversions that can be performed explicitly using const_­cast are listed below. No other conversion shall be performed explicitly using const_­cast.

  The `static_cast<>` resulted in an lvalue, so the result of the `const_cast<>` must also be an lvalue.
- What conversion does the `const_cast<>` do?
  [**7.6.1.11 Const cast**](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#4) (emphasis mine)

  > <sup>(4)</sup> For two object types `T1` and `T2`, if a pointer to `T1` can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a const_­cast, then the following conversions can also be made:
  > <sup>(4.1)</sup> **an lvalue of type** `T1` **can be explicitly converted to an lvalue of type** `T2` **using the cast** `const_­cast<T2&>`;
  > <sup>(4.2)</sup> a glvalue of type `T1` can be explicitly converted to an xvalue of type `T2` using the cast `const_­cast<T2&&>`; and
  > <sup>(4.3)</sup> if `T1` is a class type, a prvalue of type `T1` can be explicitly converted to an xvalue of type `T2` using the cast `const_­cast<T2&&>`.
  > **The result of a reference const_­cast refers to the original object if the operand is a glvalue** and to the result of applying the temporary materialization conversion otherwise.

  So the `const_cast<>` will convert the lvalue `const int&` to an `int&` lvalue, which will refer to the same object.

###### 1.3 conclusion

`const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(f))` is well-formed and will result in a lvalue int reference.

You can even extend the lifetime of the reference as per [**6.7.7 Temporary objects**](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6)

> <sup>(6)</sup> The temporary object to which the reference is bound or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference if the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained through one of the following:
> [...]
> - <sup>(6.6)</sup> a
> - <sup>(6.6.1)</sup> `const_cast` ([expr.const.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast)),
> [...]
> converting, without a user-defined conversion, a glvalue operand that is one of these expressions to a glvalue that refers to the object designated by the operand, or to its complete object or a subobject thereof,
> [...]

So this would also be legal:

```cpp
float const& f = 1.2f; 
int& i = const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(f));

i++; // legal
return i; // legal, result: 2
```

###### 1.4 notes

- It is irrelevant in this case that the operand of `static_cast<>` is a const float reference, since the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that static_cast is allowed to perform can strip away const.
  So those would also be legal:

  ```cpp
  int& i = const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(1.0f));
  // when converting to rvalue you don't even need a const_cast:
  // (due to 7.6.1.9 (4), because int&& t(1.0f); is well-formed)
  // the result of the static_cast would be an xvalue in this case. 
  int&& ii = static_cast<int&&>(1.0f);
  ```
- Because of that the following c-style casts are also well-formed:

  ```cpp
  float f = 1.2f;
  int const& i = (int const&)f; // legal, will use static_cast
  int&& ii = (int&&)f; // legal, will use static_cast
  ```

---

##### 2. why `(int&)f` doesn't work

You're technically correct in that it should work, because a c-style cast is allowed to perform this conversion sequence:

[**7.6.3 Explicit type conversion (cast notation)**](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4)

> <sup>(4)</sup> The conversions performed by
> <sup>(4.1)</sup> a `const_­cast` ([expr.const.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast)),
> <sup>(4.2)</sup> a `static_­cast` ([expr.static.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast)),
> <sup>(4.3)</sup> a `static_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
> <sup>(4.4)</sup> a `reinterpret_­cast` ([expr.reinterpret.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)), or
> <sup>(4.5)</sup> a `reinterpret_­cast` followed by a `const_­cast`,
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion. The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply, [...].

So `const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(f))` should definitely be a valid conversion sequence.

The reason why this doesn't work is actually a very, very old compiler bug.

###### 2.1 It's even an [open-std.org issue (#909)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#909):

> According to 7.6.3 [expr.cast] paragraph 4, one possible interpretation of an old-style cast is as a static_cast followed by a const_cast. One would therefore expect that the expressions marked #1 and #2 in the following example would have the same validity and meaning:
>
> ```cpp
> struct S {
>   operator const int* ();
> };
>
> void f(S& s)  {
>   const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int*>(s));  // #1
>   (int*) s;  // #2
> }
> ```
>
> However, a number of implementations issue an error on #2.
>
> Is the intent that `(T*)x` should be interpreted as something like `const_cast<T*>(static_cast<const volatile T*>(x))`

The resultion was:

> Rationale (July, 2009):
> According to the straightforward interpretation of the wording, the example should work. This appears to be just a compiler bug.

So the standard agrees with your conclusion, it's just that no compiler actually implements that interpretation.

###### 2.2 Compiler Bug Tickets

There are already open bugs for gcc & clang regarding this issue:

- gcc: [Bug 77465 (C++DR909) - [DR909] rejected C-style cast involving casting away constness from result of conversion operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77465)
- clang: [Bug 30266 - [CWG 909] C-style cast necessitating static_cast -> const_cast fails for conversion operator](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30266)

###### 2.3 why isn't this fixed yet after all those years?

I don't know, but given they have to implement a new standard roughly every 3 years now with tons of changes to the language every time it seems reasonable to ignore issues that most programmers probably won't ever encounter.

Note that this is only a problem for primitive types. My guess is that the reason for the bug is that for those the cv-qualifiers can be dropped by a `static_cast` / `reinterpret_cast` due to the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion rule.

> If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the **cv-unqualified version** of T. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is T.

Note that this bug only affects non-class types, for class-types it'll work perfectly:

```cpp
struct B { int i; };
struct D : B {};

D d;
d.i = 12;
B const& ref = d;

// works
D& k = (D&)ref;
```

There will always be a few edge-cases that are not properly implemented in each & every compiler, if it bothers you you can provide a fix & maybe they'll merge it with the next version (at least for clang & gcc).

###### 2.4 gcc code analysis

In the case of gcc a c-style cast currently gets resolved by [`cp_build_c_cast`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/typeck.c#L8821-L8871):

```cpp
tree cp_build_c_cast(location_t loc, tree type, tree expr, tsubst_flags_t complain) {
  tree value = expr;
  tree result;
  bool valid_p;
  // [...]
  /* A C-style cast can be a const_cast.  */
  result = build_const_cast_1 (loc, type, value, complain & tf_warning,
                   &valid_p);
  if (valid_p)
    {
      if (result != error_mark_node)
    {
      maybe_warn_about_useless_cast (loc, type, value, complain);
      maybe_warn_about_cast_ignoring_quals (loc, type, complain);
    }
      return result;
    }

  /* Or a static cast.  */
  result = build_static_cast_1 (loc, type, value, /*c_cast_p=*/true,
                &valid_p, complain);
  /* Or a reinterpret_cast.  */
  if (!valid_p)
    result = build_reinterpret_cast_1 (loc, type, value, /*c_cast_p=*/true,
                       &valid_p, complain);
  /* The static_cast or reinterpret_cast may be followed by a
     const_cast.  */
  if (valid_p
      /* A valid cast may result in errors if, for example, a
     conversion to an ambiguous base class is required.  */
      && !error_operand_p (result))
  {
    tree result_type;

    maybe_warn_about_useless_cast (loc, type, value, complain);
    maybe_warn_about_cast_ignoring_quals (loc, type, complain);

    /* Non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified type.  */
    if (!CLASS_TYPE_P (type))
      type = TYPE_MAIN_VARIANT (type);
    result_type = TREE_TYPE (result);

    if (!CLASS_TYPE_P (result_type) && !TYPE_REF_P (type))
      result_type = TYPE_MAIN_VARIANT (result_type);

    /* If the type of RESULT does not match TYPE, perform a
      const_cast to make it match.  If the static_cast or
      reinterpret_cast succeeded, we will differ by at most
      cv-qualification, so the follow-on const_cast is guaranteed
      to succeed.  */
    if (!same_type_p (non_reference (type), non_reference (result_type)))
    {
      result = build_const_cast_1 (loc, type, result, false, &valid_p);
      gcc_assert (valid_p);
    }

    return result;
  }

  return error_mark_node;
}
```

The implementation is basically:

- try a `const_cast`
- try a `static_cast` (while temporarily ignoring potential const mismatches)
- try a `reinterpret_cast` (while temporarily ignoring potential const mismatches)
- if there was a const mismatch in the `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` variant, slap a `const_cast` in front of it.

So for some reason `build_static_cast_1` doesn't succeed in this case, so `build_reinterpret_cast_1` gets to do it's thing (which will result in undefined behaviour due to the strict aliasing rule)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Great analysis, thanks! Looking at the code you indicate, I think passing through / acting on `c_cast_p` should fix my issue and the related CWG 909? Something like: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/compare/master...ecatmur:so-66816741

Comment: @ecatmur You made a fix for it! That's awesome :D I'm unfortunately not very familiar with the gcc code base yet. I compiled your fix & ran the tests, they worked except the `constexpr-union.C` one - line 16 (`reinterpret_cast<>` is not allowed in `constexpr` contexts). But apart from that it looks good :)

Answer (score -1):

This might be undefined behavior. But to, try and answer the question, as far as I know:

<strike>You cast `const` away, then `reinterpret_cast` it as a `int&`.</strike>  (**)
It's not a `static_cast`?
It's already a reference to a lvalue that isn't *[pointer-interconvertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)* to `int&`.  (*)

The result of that `reinterpret_cast`(?) would be undefined behavior; It'd violate the [strict aliasing rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing).

You can check that before trying by using `std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of_v<>`. See: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of)

If we ignore `const` it <strike>still doesn't</strike> make(s) sense.
The more I keep reading about this, the least certain I become of anything. This is why we tell you not to use c-style casts.

Notes (*): That's wrong, or is it? More than one way to skin this cast…
(**): It's not that… I don't know what I'm saying there…

Comment: "You cast const away, then reinterpret_cast it as a int&." But according to  the C++ Standard, a C-style cast performs a reinterpret_cast *followed by* a const_cast, not the other way round. And that only if a static_cast followed by a const_cast is not viable; but it is viable in this case, as demonstrated.

Comment: You can *implicitly* add `const`. Removing it, must be explicit. [\[expr.static.cast\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.static.cast-8)

Comment: Actually, just read the whole chapter [\[expr.cast\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast) (as I did, 5 times, yesterday) I'm way too tired to read this small font. 
Of note is "If a conversion can be interpreted in more than one way as a static_­cast followed by a const_­cast, the conversion is ill-formed."

Comment: OK, so what's that alternate conversion path? Also, if it were ill-formed (note, not ill-formed NDR) then shouldn't this be rejected?

Comment: @ecatmur:  *"But according to the C++ Standard, a C-style cast performs a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast, not the other way round."*. You just confuse me, does this means: `reintrepret_cast<new-type>(const_cast<new-type>(expression))` or the other way round?

Comment: @cpper no, the other way round - the inner cast occurs before (is followed by) the outer cast.